# can't get image from URL? (NSURLErrorDomain error -1100)

Tags: ios, ios9, nsurl

I am trying to load this jpeg: https://i.groupme.com/638x640.jpeg.d4f31c747b534baca03d12db5a2b6193

but I get the error `The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1100.)`

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778167/undocumented-nsurlerrordomain-error-codes-1001-1003-and-1004-using-storeki), I found the error means: `kCFURLErrorFileDoesNotExist`. which is strange because there is definitely an image there.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868247/images-from-foursquare-are-nsurlerrorfiledoesnotexist-1100), it seemed the issue was with the `https` protocol, but after I implemented the solution to switch to `http`, I got the error:

`App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.` ... `The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.`

And the same error continues to popup after making the necessary plist changes:

[image]

How do I download this image in iOS?

**UPDATE**

So I found that it does download OK with `https` if I use this code:

```
NSData* theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://i.groupme.com/638x640.jpeg.d4f31c747b534baca03d12db5a2b6193"]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:theData];
```

but it doesn't work if I use this library: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

No one else seems to have had issues with `https` and that library though, so I think its still a settings problem on my end?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transport Security has Blocked a cleartext HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Comment: if you're trying to close this, explain why. If you read the whole question, you'd know it's not a duplicate of that other question

Comment: Your URL contains https so there is no issues for `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads`. Please show me the code to help you out.... It must work work with https not need to go to http....

Comment: @NiravGadhiya thanks for the tip, after simplifying my code to provide an example, I got it to download. It seems the problem only occurs with the image loading library I am using, but they have an `https` url in their example code, so maybe its probably still a problem on my end https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You are providing a wrong domain name.**

### Solution

Delete all the plist settings you have added manually, add this in plist----

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>i.groupme.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

**Plist Screenshot**

[image]

### Code to download image

```
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://i.groupme.com/638x640.jpeg.d4f31c747b534baca03d12db5a2b6193"];
 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
 UIImage *result = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

### Image download Success screenshot

[image]

Comment: doesn't `NSIncludesSubdomains` include the `i.` part?

Comment: Thanks! I just used that code and it worked, seems to have been the library I was using. However, I'm still confused as to why this library doesn't work for me: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage. They have `https` in their example code, so this is definitely still a problem on my end.